# add 2 entity from different DB with EF

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

does anyone know if is possible to add 2 entities into EF model from 2 DB.

If not, what suggestions can you gave me to build a query that affects 2 databases

Comment: So you basically want to have one EF model that has entities from two different databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no direct support for this scenario, MSFT members state it in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/cad06147-2168-4c20-ac23-98f32987b126/).
However, Rafael Krisller and Akhil Karkera suggest some workarounds [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4acbf58d-30a5-44ec-9b3b-784af9b9bbaa).

Comment: Do you have any idea if, NHibernate Linq support this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to map a conceptual model, to two storage models.

If you find yourself needing to join between 2 databases, I have seen this accomplished via Data Services.  You basically talk via URIs.  So you query for URI to some set of data (ultimately gives you the surrogate key) and then you use that to query for data in the second database.

Comment: I didn't understand "you might want to think about reorganizing your servers."?

Comment: I took it out.  I was a partial thought that I never finished.